# PHPBREW configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's

Tags: php, openssl, php7

I'm trying to install an alternative version of PHP.
For this reason, I'm using PHPBrew.

And when I try to compile it, I have followed error:

> configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's

I'm trying to manual install OpenSSL by this tutorial:

http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-install-and-update-openssl-on-centos-6-centos-7/

Also, I've to install OpenSSL-devel package, `pkg-config` package.
When I'm typing OpenSSL version I receive:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2k 26 Jan 2017
```

But OPENSSLDIR is still empty.
But when I compiled openssl it displayed follow the path:

```
/usr/local/ssl
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my full command:

```
phpbrew --debug install 7.0.11 +fpm +gd +json +mbstring +mysql +pdo +opcache +curl +cli +mcrypt +filter +hash +zip +xml +tokenizer +openssl=/usr/lib/ -- --with-libdir=/usr/lib/
```

Also I've tried this:

```
phpbrew --debug install 7.0.11 +fpm +gd +json +mbstring +mysql +pdo +opcache +curl +cli +mcrypt +filter +hash +zip +xml +tokenizer +openssl
```

And another different paths to the openssl

Please help me! I have been suffering almost two weeks.

I'm using CentOS 6.

Thank you!

Comment: How did solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have done this,

```
mv /usr/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl-orig  
cd /usr/bin  
ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
```

Also have you tried varying the openssl path in your install command?  I'd try `/usr/local/`, `/usr/local/ssl/`, or `/usr/local/lib` and see if any of those help

```
phpbrew --debug install 7.0.11 +fpm +gd +json +mbstring +mysql +pdo +opcache +curl +cli +mcrypt +filter +hash +zip +xml +tokenizer +openssl=/usr/local/lib/ -- --with-libdir=/usr/lib/
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much! I've solved my problem more easier - I'vs just updated my default PHP from 5.x to 7.1 and now it's working fine!